# How to show spaces between 3 divs and keep them on the same row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML, to show 3 divs beside each other using bootstrap syntax:

```css
.main-background {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.main-Image {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-h3 {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Lora, sans-serif;
  color: #162b3b;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 40px 40px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-footer {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #162b3b;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-xl-4 main-background">
    <div class="main-Image">
      <img src="~/img/How_It_Works_Personalized-1.jpg" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, 250px" width="250" />

    </div>

    <div class="main-h3">
      1. Personalized Recommendations

    </div>


    <div class="main-footer">
      Receive practice-specific, data-driven recommendations and care plans
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-4 main-background">
    <div class="main-Image">
      <img src="~/img/How_It_Works_Personalized-1.jpg" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, 250px" width="250" />

    </div>

    <div class="main-h3">
      1. Personalized Recommendations

    </div>


    <div class="main-footer">
      Receive practice-specific, data-driven recommendations and care plans
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-4 main-background">
    <div class="main-Image">
      <img src="~/img/How_It_Works_Personalized-1.jpg" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, 250px" width="250" />

    </div>

    <div class="main-h3">
      1. Personalized Recommendations

    </div>


    <div class="main-footer">
      Receive practice-specific, data-driven recommendations and care plans
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Currently the 3 divs will be shown aligned to each other, as follow:

[image]

So how I can add some horizontal space between the 3 divs without causing the last div to go to a separate row? Now if I try to add `margin-left` and `margin-right` to the middle divs this will cause the last div to move to a new line!

Comment: You should take a look at Bootstrap's flexbox utility classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex (specifically, using `.d-flex` and `.justify-content-between`)

Comment: @J.Titus can you advice more please?

Comment: @JohnJohn, flexbox can achieve what you need. `display:flex` & `justify-content: space-between` are the css properties which you need to apply to the parent container. Since you are using bootstrap, as @Titus mentioned, goto that link and check for the class names to apply in the parent container.

Comment: @akshithDayanand i tried the following `<div class="row" style="justify-content: space-between">` but did not add any space.. am i missing something?

Comment: @akshithDayanand also correct me if i am wrong.. the link does not show how to add space between divs?

Comment: @JohnJohn You're also using `col-xl-4` on the three columns. Since 4*3 = 12 (the max columns) you won't see any space between when using `justify-content-between`. Try changing them to `col-xl-3`, and use `d-flex justify-content-between` on your main `row`.

Comment: @JohnJohn how much space are you trying to add? With the BootStrap grid, you already have 30px (15px on all `col-*` elements)

Comment: @disinfor i need to add `5px` max .. but in my case the 3 divs will be shown beside each other... no space... check the image i provided

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You are trying to add more padding between your columns, correct? Currently, it should be 30px, since each column has 15px of padding both sides. So you want to add 5px more, so they have a little more space between? But you are running into an issue since the last one will wrap if you use margin?

Comment: @disinfor seems there is no padding by default

Comment: There is definitely padding by default. Each of your `col-xl-4 main-background` will have padding. What size screen are you looking at this on? I noticed you are adding padding to those elements when you don't need to. Change your `col-xl-4` to `col-md-4` or `col-sm-4`

Comment: @disinfor i am using wide screen on my desktop..

Comment: @disinfor also if i try to use `col-xl-3` instead of `col-xl-4` then there will be wasted space to the left...

Answer (score 1):

You can use these codes, it will meet what you want. With `flex-wrap:nowrap !important;`

If you use them it will not go to the bottom line.

```css
.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap !important;
  background-color:red;
  justify-content:safe center;
}

.main-background {
  background-color:#ddd;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-right:15px;
  width:auto;
}

.main-Image {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-h3 {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Lora, sans-serif;
  color: #162b3b;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 40px 40px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content:center;
}

.main-footer {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #162b3b;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-xl-4 main-background">
    <div class="main-Image">
      <img src="https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, 250px" width="250" />

    </div>

    <div class="main-h3">
      1. Personalized Recommendations

    </div>


    <div class="main-footer">
      Receive practice-specific, data-driven recommendations and care plans
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-4 main-background">
    <div class="main-Image">
      <img src="https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, 250px" width="250" />

    </div>

    <div class="main-h3">
      1. Personalized Recommendations

    </div>


    <div class="main-footer">
      Receive practice-specific, data-driven recommendations and care plans
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-4 main-background">
    <div class="main-Image">
      <img src="https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, 250px" width="250" />

    </div>

    <div class="main-h3">
      1. Personalized Recommendations

    </div>


    <div class="main-footer">
      Receive practice-specific, data-driven recommendations and care plans
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

### EDIT FOR MOBILE

This allows the bottom line for mobile

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
.row {
  flex-wrap:wrap !important;
}
}
```

Comment: but after doing your modification, if i render the page on my mobile the 3 divs wil not expand vertically ....